# How to print a dictionary with multiple values without brackets?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have this so far:

```
class Wine:
    def __init__(self, key):
        a = {}
        value = []
        a.setdefault(key, [])

    def addYear(self, value):
        a[key].insert(1, value)

    def addProd(self, value):
        a[key].insert(2, value)
    
    def addCountry(self, value):
        a[key].insert(3, value)
    
    def addPrice(self, value):
        a[key].insert(4, value)
    
    def __str__(self):
        for key, value in a.items():
            value = ', '.join(map(str, value))
            print("{}, {}".format(key, value))
        
b = Wine("Bread and Butter Pinot Noir")
b.addYear("2017")
b.addProd("Sonoma County")
b.addCountry("USA")
b.addPrice("30 USD")
b.__str__()
```

I want the output to look like this:

Bread and Butter Pinot Noir, 2017, Sonoma County, USA, 30 USD

But it says "name 'a' is not defined"

Comment: you need to bind these values to the instance through `self.<attr>`. I'd suggest a tutorial on how classes work

Comment: `a.insert` does not behave as you think it does. If the list isn't long enough for the inserted index, it'll just add it at the end of the list. So, calling `b.addPrice()` before `b.addYear()` will lead to the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understood Classes real well but still you need to use self.attribute to use any attributes inside class functions, here is a code that will give you the required output

```
class Wine:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.a = {}
        self.key = key
        self.value = []
        self.a.setdefault(key, [])

    def addYear(self, value):
        self.a[self.key].insert(1, value)

    def addProd(self, value):
        self.a[self.key].insert(2, value)
    
    def addCountry(self, value):
        self.a[self.key].insert(3, value)
    
    def addPrice(self, value):
        self.a[self.key].insert(4, value)
    
    def __str__(self):
        for key, value in self.a.items():
            value = ', '.join(map(str, value))
            print("{}, {}".format(key, value))
        
b = Wine("Bread and Butter Pinot Noir")
b.addYear("2017")
b.addProd("Sonoma County")
b.addCountry("USA")
b.addPrice("30 USD")
b.__str__()
```